# Interpreting a hex number as decimal

Tags: c, hex, radix

I have an embedded system running C-code which works pretty straightforwardly; it reads characters via a serial connection, interprets the received chars as hexadecimal numbers and depending on what was received, proceeds to do something else. However, there is one very special case where the chars received are decimal instead of hex. Since this case is very rare (kind of an error case of an error case), I don't wish to modify the actual character reception to decide whether to interpret the received value as dec or hex, but rather to add a quick algorithm into the case handling where I change the number into decimal.

What would you say is the fastest (as in most efficient processor-wise) way of doing this? Since the software is running on a small MCU, any C library functions are not an option since I don't wish to add any more unnecessary #include's, so a purely mathematical algorithm is what I'm searching for.

Just to be clear, I'm not asking the quickest way to do a basic hex-to-dec- conversion as in 0x45 -> dec 69, but what I want to do is to transform eg. 0x120 into decimal 120.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Sorry, I'll try to explain in more detail. The actual code is way too long, and I think pasting it here is unnecessary. So here's what happens:

First I read a received number from the serial line, let's say "25". Then I turn it into hex number, so I have a variable with the read value, let's say X = 0x25. This works already fine, and I don't want to do modifications to this. What I would like to do now in this very special case is just to change the interpretation of the variable so that instead of X == 0x25, X==25. Hexadecimal 0x25 turns into decimal 25. There has to be some kind of mathematical formula for such a change, without the need of any processor-specific instructions or library functions?

Comment: It is called [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal). If it is a rare case, I would use library functions if available. Some processors have BCD related instructions.

Comment: if the sequence of chars you're looking for is `0x120`, then just create a char pointer like so: `char *decimal = &inChar[2];` and `int number = atoi(decimal);`... though I suspect what you're looking for is a bit more complex. You really ought to elaborate on this (show some code, be more specific)

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to explain in more detail. The actual code is way too long, and I think unnecessary. So here's what happens:

Comment: Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: how do you know it is a decimal value that you receive since you say in a comment that you do not get 0x in front of hex values, e.g. 25 is both a valid hex number and a valid decimal number.

Comment: The system also has other interfaces to the "real world", and based on events registered from those, the right course of action is taken. This is exactly why the need for such a conversion; only numbers are received, and the interpretation depends on the situation.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding correctly, you've already converted a stream of ASCII characters into a `char/int` variable, assuming them to be a stream of hex-digits.  In some cases, they were actually a stream of decimal digits (e.g. you received `45` and, treating this as hex, got a variable with value `69` when -- in one special case -- you actuially want its value to be `45`.

Assuming two-characters, (`00`-`ff` in general, but for "was meant to be decimal" we're talking `00`-`99`) then:

```
int hexVal = GetHexStringFromSerialPort() ;
int decVal = 10*(hexVal >> 4) + (hexVal & 0x0f) ;
```

should do the trick.  If you've got longer strings, you'll need to extend the concept further.

Comment: This looks like just what I'm looking for, I'll see where I end up with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just do a simple `while` loop like this, supposing `onum` and `dnum` are unsigned integers

```
dnum = 0;
while (onum) {
  digit = onum & 0xF;
  dnum = dnum*10 + digit;
  onum >>= 4;
}
```

this supposes that `onum` is really of the form that you describe (no hexdigits that are `>9`). It just succs the least significant hexdigit out of your number and adds it to your decimal.

Comment: This "reverses" the number. For onum = 0x1234 you will get 4321 in dnum.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, right. One would have to do a second loop to revert that, again.

Answer (score 0):

Checking if your string starts with `0x` characters and removing them should do the trick.

Comment: The character data I'm receiving is not prefixed with 0x, I'm receiving just the numbers in a comma-separated form. Furthermore, I don't wish to add any kind of checking to the actual reception routine, I rather just manipulate the received number if the situation demands it.